# Must be a non abstract type with public parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constructor, abstract

I read the answers to some similar questions to mine but couldn't find a good explanation to my case. Please, correct me, if I'm wrong :)

I have three classes - a base abstract class, called EmailData, and two other classes that derive from the base class. I have not included one of the inheriting classes and most of the members of the other classes to make the example more obvious.

```
private abstract class EmailData
    {
        public EmailData(DataRow emailDataRow)
        {
            vehicleOwner = emailDataRow["owner"].ToString();
        }

        public string VehicleOwner { get { return vehicleOwner; } }

        private string vehicleOwner;
    }

    private class DeliveryEmailData : EmailData
    {
        public DeliveryEmailData(DataRow deliveryData)
            : base(deliveryData)
        {
            orderNumber = deliveryData["ordernumber"].ToString();
        }

        public string OrderNumber { get { return orderNumber; } }

        private string orderNumber;
    }
```

I have a generic class, that uses one of the two classes that derive from the base class EmailData, and looks like this:

```
private class Email<T> where T : EmailData, new()
    {
        public Email(DataTable emailDataTable)
        {
            // Get the number of rows.
            int rowsNumber = emailDataTable.Rows.Count;

            emailsData = new T[rowsNumber];

            for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
            {
                // Store the appropriate data in the arrays.
                emailsData[i] = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), emailDataTable.Rows[i]);
            }

            // Get the email of the recipient.
            recipientEmail = emailDataTable.Rows[0]["delivery_email"].ToString();
        }

        public T[] EmailsData { get { return emailsData; } }
        public string RecipientEmail { get { return recipientEmail; } }

        private T[] emailsData;
        private string recipientEmail;
    }
```

If I decide to make a new instance of the Email class:

```
Email<DeliveryEmailData> email = new Email<DeliveryEmailData>(someDataTableObject);
```

I get the following error:

```
'DeliveryEmailData' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T'
```

When I add a parameterless constructor to both the base and derived classes, the error no longer shows up. The problem is that I don't need a parameterless constructor, but one that receives a DataTable object.

So, does anyone know what is wrong with this?

Comment: That's because of the generic constraint `where T : new()`. Just leave that away.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have constrained `T` as `T : new()` which meant it must be non-abstract i.e. you must be able to create instance of type `T` and it must have parameterless constructor.
The problem not in

```
public Email(DataTable emailDataTable){}
```

which receives `DataTable` but in

```
public EmailData(DataRow emailDataRow){}
```

you can remove constraint `new()` to solve your problem.

Comment: I've been using C# since 2007 and I swear I discover a new feature every week. Thanks for this week's feature.